# How is MVC changing the paths to jqueryui images?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

The graphics for my jQueryUI date picker were not showing up; when I looked in the network trace I saw that I was getting a 404, but the image exists in my project but the path to the image in the trace was incorrect.
[image: jquery image file path]

The `ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png` file is in `~/Content/themes/base/images` and the `jquery.ui.datepicker.css` file is loaded. Looking in the css file it references the graphic `url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png)`. The `images` folder is in the same folder as the css so the path looks correct to me. So why is it trying to find the file at `/Content/images`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting same issue as you when I deploy to production server which has IIS 6. But if I deploy to my local IIS, it works fine.

I did quick fix by copying the "iquery > images" to "content > images", but this is not a good fix.

If you find any other solution, please kindly share me.

Thanks.
Alin